# Amazon Widget Firefox Overlap Issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, amazon-web-services

I have a wordpress powered website, http://techpatrol.eu

In the sidebar on the right of my site, the Amazon search widget doesn't display text and images and overlaps the two. I've tried playing around with various different options and sizes on Amazon, but everytime I use images they seem to overlap no matter what options I set.

Does anyone know how I might solve this? This only happens in Firefox and displays fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script..I have edited the script according to your website....

```
<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/55511231939/mainscript.js"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&ID=V20070822%2FUS%2Fwidgetsamazon-20%2F8002%2F55f3e72b-7818-49e8-8847-c93e9c59800f&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.com Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width:40px; in the inline in every image tag instead of using image-width property.. that will fix the problem

```
  <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41LbH--C2nL._SL75_.jpg" style="border: medium none; margin: 0px; text-decoration: none; width: 40px;" height="53" width="40">
```

This is the snapshot taken in firefox[image]

Comment: Hi Bala, thanks a lot for the reply! Where exactly do I put that code?  The code I'm currently using in my sidebar:

Comment: `<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&ID=V20070822%2FUS%2Ftechpatroleu-20%2F8002%2Fc6145c96-8492-4189-ae67-f625dc5e31fa"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&ID=V20070822%2FUS%2Ftechpatroleu-20%2F8002%2Fc6145c96-8492-4189-ae67-f625dc5e31fa&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.com Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>`

Comment: I tried to put the code you gave me in various places in this code, but I couldn't get it to work - what am I doing wrong please?  Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Use this script...I have edited the script according to your website..`<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/55511231939/mainscript.js"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&ID=V20070822%2FUS%2Fwidgetsamazon-20%2F8002%2F55f3e72b-7818-49e8-8847-c93e9c59800f&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.com Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>`

Comment: Hi Bala, you are a star, thank you very much!  That worked perfectly!
Thanks again for all your help!